# Go slice overwrite

Tags: go

Here is the source code:

```
package main

func main() {
    testSlice()
}

func testSlice() {
    slice := make([]int, 0)
    //slice = append(slice, 1)  ①
    //slice = append(slice, 1, 2)  ②
    //slice = append(slice, 1, 2, 3)  ③
    //slice = append(slice, 1, 2, 3, 4)  ④
    slice = append(slice, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  ⑤
    //slice = append(slice, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  ⑥

    slice2 := append(slice, 1)
    slice3 := append(slice, 2)

    for _, i := range slice2 {
        print(i)
    }
    println()
    for _, i := range slice3 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
123451
123452
```

Actual output:

```
123452
123452
```

The output of ①~⑥ except ⑤ is as expected. But why ⑤ `slice3` overwrites `slice2`?

Is the reason related to pointer or slice resize?

Comment: The `slice` slice has sufficient capacity to append an element without reallocating the backing array.  The two append operations write over the same element in the backing array.  See [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) if you are not familiar with how slices work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20277579/13906951) for a really helpful explanation of what a slice actually is before reading the rest of my answer. It might be easier to understand what's going on by printing out the actual slice headers. See the following example code (and [go playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/tKmfv-TUSJC)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    testSlice()
}

func testSlice() {
    slice := make([]int, 0)
    slice = append(slice, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice)))
    slice2 := append(slice, 1)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice2)))
    slice3 := append(slice, 2)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&slice3)))

    for _, i := range slice2 {
        print(i)
    }
    println()
    for _, i := range slice3 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

This will print something like this:

```
&{Data:824634441776 Len:5 Cap:6}
&{Data:824634441776 Len:6 Cap:6}
&{Data:824634441776 Len:6 Cap:6}
```

This shows that all variables `slice`, `slice2`, and `slice3` are pointing at the same data (`Data` which is a pointer to the first element of the slice) but the slice headers themselves are different. When you're performing your `append`s, you are modifying the underlying slice shared by all the variables, and storing new slice headers into new variables. The slice headers for `slice2` and `slice3` are looking at the same slice of data, so when you come along and perform your append for `slice3`, you're overwriting the 6th element in the underlying slice that is shared by all the variables.